# Table cells not rendering as desired for ngFor

Tags: angular

I am trying to render a dynamic table with the ngFor directive. It's not rendering as desired.

This is my html:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
<td>{{item[1]}} </td>
<td>{{item[0]}} </td>
<td>{{item[2]}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is in my controller:

```
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit  {
items = [];

onSubmit(quantity, product_name, product_price){

localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(quantity, product_name, product_price));

this.items.push( String(quantity), product_name, product_price );
}
}
```

It is rendered as follows:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>quantity</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>product_name</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<tr>
<td>product_price</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

My desired rendering is:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>quantity</td>
<td>product_name</td>
<td>product_price</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give us your JSON please ? How to read it depends on its shape.

Comment: Put a break point in ngAfterViewInit and tell us what's in the items array. https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: can you update the data on your `items` array

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over `items` which is an array that holds the values. To extract the headers , you must `fetch` it from one of the objects if you want to do it dynamically.

Following is the code that solves your problem (you should do it when first element is inserted in your array) :

```
 this.headers = Object.keys(this.items[0])
```

Here is the html code :

```
<table border="2">
  <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let h of headers"> {{h}} </th>
  </tr>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
<td>{{item.quantity}} </td>
<td>{{item.product_name}}</td>
<td>{{item.product_price}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the working example :  [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ze9wym)

Comment: I don't need the headers and using {{item.quantity}},{{item.product_name}},{{item.product_price}} instead of {{item[1]}},{{item[0]}},{{item[2]}} renders nothing because I am not getting the elements from a json file. Thanks programoholic anyway for the valiant effort.

Comment: It's not clear in the question what are you trying to achieve.. may be explain more what you want ??  Doing item[1] , Item[0] is not the correct way to access arrays in ngFor

Comment: My array is created in the onSubmit function and it's created like this
this.items.push( String(quantity), product_name, product_price );
so I have to access it with indexes.

Comment: The Items array actually needs to be saved to localStorage. How do I push an array to localStorage?

Comment: The answer was posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/ROO8TCiw5Qw